# Why is the set command throwing an error?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a program in batch but CMD keeps telling me that the syntax of the SET command is incorrect:

```
choice /m "Show or hide?" /c SH
set choice=%errorlevel%
```

What's going on? It's supposed to not throw any errors.

Entire script:

```
rem @echo off
choice /m "Show or hide?" /c SH
set choice=%errorlevel%
if %choice%==1 (
net user administrator /active:yes
) else if %choice%==2
net user administrator /active:no
) else (
echo "Invalid option"
)
pause
```

Comment: You were reading the error message incorrectly.  Yes it shows the `SET` command above the error message but the error was on the code below the error message which said `) else if 1==2`.

Comment: Technically I wouldn't call it an `Invalid option`, because only two options can be chosen, `[S]`, or `[H]`, _(if you don't include `[CTRL]`+`[C]`)_, anything else would be an error condition, i.e. ErrorLevel 255. so I'd suggest that should read, `An error occurred`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `(` at end of line

) else if %choice%==2 `(`